# Python Pexpect and Minicom not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pexpect

I need to perform a number of processes to Switch that I can only execute through serial port.
To do this I use Pexpect and Minicom.
I am able to execute the command `child.sendcontrol(“c”)` to open the menu.
But from the menu I can't choose any of the options.

When I do this manually through the Minicom it works without a problem.
what could be the problem?

Note I use `child.after` to verify that the actions were actually performed.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pexpect

print("Waiting for connection....") # for check
child = pexpect.spawn("minicom")
child.expect(r".*Hit.*", timeout=120)
test = child.after
fileNameone = "/root/Desktop/fileone.txt"
file = open(fileNameone, "wb")
file.write(test)
file.close

child.sendcontrol("c")
print("menu") # for check

child.expect(".*selection.*", timeout=10)
testtwo = child.after
fileNametwo = "/root/Desktop/filetwo.txt"
file = open(fileNametwo, "wb")
file.write(testtwo)
file.close
child.sendline("1")
print("choose 1") # for check


child.expect(".*Gateway.*", timeout=40)
child.sendline("admin")
child.expect(".*Password.*", timeout=10)
child.sendline("admin")
print("connect!") # for check
```

This is the request to press ctrl + c to open the menu (The log was taken from pexpect through minicom):

```
[23;80H [24;1H************ Hit 'Ctrl + C' for boot menu ************
[23;80H [24;1H
[23;80H [24;1H 2
```

This is the menu (The log was taken from pexpect through minicom):

```
[23;80H [24;1HWelcome to Embedded Boot Menu :
[23;80H [24;1H
[23;80H [24;1H[24;9H1. Start in normal Mode
[23;80H [24;1H[24;9H2. Start in debug Mode
[23;80H [24;1H[24;9H3. Start in maintenance Mode
[23;80H [24;1H[24;9H4. Restore to Factory Defaults (local)
[23;80H [24;1H[24;9H5. Install/Update Image from Network
[23;80H [24;1H[24;9H6. Restart Boot-Loader
[23;80H [24;1H[24;9H7. Run Hardware diagnostics
[23;80H [24;1H[24;9H8. Upload preset configuration file
[23;80H [24;1H[24;9H9. Delete preset configuration file
[23;80H [24;1H
[23;80H [24;1H[24;9HPlease enter your selection (pres
```

I'm trying to choose option 1, for the test.
But it is not performed.
The same goes for each menu option.

```
child.expect(".*selection.*", timeout=10)
child.sendline("1")
```

This is the error:
(Should not take more than 15 seconds to boot)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 33, in <module>
    child.expect(".*Gateway.*", timeout=40)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 344, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 372, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 181, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 144, in timeout
    raise exc
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.
<pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0x7fefa0934a90>
command: /usr/bin/minicom
args: ['/usr/bin/minicom']
buffer (last 100 chars): b's ENTER to finish) :1\r\n\x1b[23;80H \x1b[24;1H'
before (last 100 chars): b's ENTER to finish) :1\r\n\x1b[23;80H \x1b[24;1H'
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 10862
child_fd: 5
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(b'.*Gateway.*')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem, minicom must get manual enter.
Even that `child.sendline` sends with Enter.
For some reason the minicom doesn't get the enter.
`Child.send ("\r\n")` doesn't work either.

The solution is:

After the line `child.sendline("1")`

I added the line `child.sendcontrol("m")` for press enter.

Now it works properly.